# Recursive function not returning all children in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a Mysql Table

[image: My table screenshot]

This is my Model

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Categories extends Model {
    protected $table = 'category';
    protected $fillable = ['category_name', 'parent_id', 'category_level', 'last_level', 'description', 'category_image'];
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categories', 'parent_id');
    }
    public function children() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Categories','parent_id');
    }
}
```

and this is my Controller Method

```
public function create() {
    $parentCategory = Categories::all(); 
    return view('admin.add_category')->with('parentCategory', $parentCategory);
}
```

I want to get this Result

[image: Result screenshot]

How is it possible?

**EDIT**

And This is My View:

```
<select name="category_id" id="p_category_id" class="form-control">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Select Cateory</option>
    <option selected="" value="">Category</option>
    @foreach ($parentCategory as $category)  
        @foreach ($category->children as $child)
            <option value="{{ $category->id }}" placeholder="choose parent category">{{ $child->category_name }}</option>
        @endforeach                                        
     @endforeach
</select>
```

I want this result:

```
Category
Bangladesg
----Dhaka
---------Mirpur
---------------Senpara
---------Mohammadpur
----Rangpur
```

Comment: @Epodax Didn't see that in the review, will take a look

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a custom method to achieve this. Because what you want to do is list all children and the children of the children and so on. That will not work with 1 foreach loop(or, not a foreach loop like you have right now). You can hardcore foreach loops in foreach loops, but thats ugly code and then you are hardcoding the maximum levels of categories.

The method you have to create should be a self-referencing method so you can have as many children categories as you want.

Maybe you should try some packages who do the job for you and are easy to implement:

https://github.com/gazsp/baum

or

https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset